# Combine/grouping objects with the same key and apply it also to child objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. I need to combine all the objects on the array that have the same key.

This is the original array:

```
const original = [
    { Country: 'Asia', Year: 2021, Month: 'January', Sport: 'Football' },
    { Country: 'Asia', Year: 2021, Month: 'March', Sport: 'Basketball' },
    { Country: 'Asia', Year: 2022, Month: 'May', Sport: 'Basketball' },
    { Country: 'Europe', Year: 2022, Month: 'June', Sport: 'Basketball' },
    { Country: 'Europe', Year: 2022, Month: 'October', Sport: 'Volley' },
];
```

I need to combine the objects so the output is as follows:

```
const result = [
    {
        code: 'AS',
        name: 'Asia',
        childs: [
            {
                code: 'AS_2021',
                name: '2021',
                childs: [
                    { code: 'AS_2021_January', name: 'January', childs: [{ code: 'AS_2021_January_Football', name: 'Football' }] },
                    { code: 'AS_2021_March', name: 'March', childs: [{ code: 'AS_2021_March_Basketball', name: 'Basketball' }] },
                ],
            },
            {
                code: 'AS_2022',
                name: '2022',
                childs: [{ code: 'AS_2022_May', name: 'May', childs: [{ code: 'AS_2022_May_Basketball', name: 'Basketball' }] }],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        code: 'EU',
        name: 'Europe',
        childs: [
            {
                code: 'EU_2022',
                name: '2022',
                childs: [
                    { code: 'EU_2022_June', name: 'June', childs: [{ code: 'EU_2022_June_Basketball', name: 'Basketball' }] },
                    { code: 'EU_2022_October', name: 'October', childs: [{ code: 'EU_2022_October_Volley', name: 'Volley' }] },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the elements of the `original` array and keep pushing new or update existing object if exists. Not sure how you generate `code` as you haven't explained it, but this is the rest of the `result` array:

```js
const original = [{
    Country: 'Asia',
    Year: 2021,
    Month: 'January',
    Sport: 'Football'
  },
  {
    Country: 'Asia',
    Year: 2021,
    Month: 'March',
    Sport: 'Basketball'
  },
  {
    Country: 'Asia',
    Year: 2022,
    Month: 'May',
    Sport: 'Basketball'
  },
  {
    Country: 'Europe',
    Year: 2022,
    Month: 'June',
    Sport: 'Basketball'
  },
  {
    Country: 'Europe',
    Year: 2022,
    Month: 'October',
    Sport: 'Volley'
  },
];

var result = [];
for (let element of original) {
  let existingCountry = result.find(ele => ele.name == element.Country)
  if (existingCountry) {
    let existingYear = existingCountry.children.find(ele => ele.name == element.Year);
    if (existingYear) {
      let existingMonth = existingYear.children.find(ele => ele.name == element.Month)
      if (existingMonth) {
        existingMonth.children.push({
          name: element.Sport
        })
      } else {
        existingYear.children.push({
          name: element.Month,
          children: [{
            name: element.Sport
          }]
        })
      }
    } else {
      existingCountry.children.push({
        name: element.Year,
        children: [{
          name: element.Month,
          children: [{
            name: element.Sport
          }]
        }]
      })
    }
  } else {
    result.push({
      name: element.Country,
      children: [{
        name: element.Year,
        children: [{
          name: element.Month,
          children: [{
            name: element.Sport
          }]
        }]
      }]
    })
  }
}

console.log(result)
```